# Do I need to change the delimiter when creating a procedure using PHP MyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, myisam, phpmyadmin

I know I need to change the delimiter when manually creating a MySql Procedure but I can't find evidence on how to do it when using the PHP MyAdmin new procedure form or is it even necessary to change it when using this form? Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to specify the DELIMITER via the Routines UI tool/form.